# Decimal.MinValue costs more than you expect

Tags: c#, performance, decimal

Recently during profiling session one method caught my eye, which in profiler's decompiled version looked like this:

```
public static double dec2f(Decimal value)
{
    if (value == new Decimal(-1, -1, -1, true, (byte) 0))
        return double.MinValue;
    try
    {
      return (double) value;
    }
    catch
    {
      return double.MinValue;
    }
}
```

This is part of the legacy code written years ago and according to the profiler (which was in sampling mode) there were too much time wasted in this method. In my opinion this is because try-catch block preventing inlining and I spent some time to refresh my memories about decimal to double conversion tricks. After ensuring this conversion can't throw, I removed try-catch block.

But when I looked again at simplified version of *source* code, I wondered why decompiled version shows strange Decimal constuctor while it is simple Decimal.MinValue usage:

```
public static double dec2f(decimal value)
{
    if (value == DecimalMinValue)
    {
        return Double.MinValue;
    }

    return (double)value;
}
```

First, I thought it is a decompiler's bug, but fortunately it also shows IL version of method:

```
    public static double dec2f(Decimal value)
    {
      if (value == new Decimal(-1, -1, -1, true, (byte) 0))
.maxstack 6
.locals init (
[0] float64 V_0
)
IL_0000: ldarg.0      // 'value'
IL_0001: ldc.i4.m1    
IL_0002: ldc.i4.m1    
IL_0003: ldc.i4.m1    
IL_0004: ldc.i4.1     
IL_0005: ldc.i4.0     
IL_0006: newobj       instance void [mscorlib]System.Decimal::.ctor(int32, int32, int32, bool, unsigned int8)
IL_000b: call         bool [mscorlib]System.Decimal::op_Equality(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal, valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal)
IL_0010: brfalse.s    IL_001c
        return double.MinValue;
```

Well, looks like it is true that the Decimal constructor is involved EVERY time you use 'constant' like Decimal.MinValue! So next question arises - what is inside this constructor and is there any difference in using Decimal.MinValue and defining local field like:

```
static readonly decimal DecimalMinValue = Decimal.MinValue;
```

Well, the answer is - there is a difference if every penny counts in your case:

```
                     Method |        Mean |    StdDev |
--------------------------- |------------ |---------- |
 CompareWithDecimalMinValue | 178.4235 ns | 0.4395 ns |
   CompareWithLocalMinValue |  98.0991 ns | 2.2803 ns |
```

And the reason of this behavior is DecimalConstantAttribute which specified how to create a decimal every time you use one of the decimal's 'constants'.

The question is - I understand that cost of calling Decimal's constructor every time you use it as 'constant' affects almost nobody, but... Why it is implemented this way anyway? Is it because the lack of notion of copy-constructor from C++?

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I think you've missed the point, which is that the constructor call is in the decompiled code. Note that the CLR doesn't have any notion of a constant `decimal`, so it *does* make a call to the constructor in the generated IL.

Comment: What are you actually *asking* here? This looks like a perfectly reasonable blog post, but it's not clear that it begins on Stack Overflow as a *question*...

Comment: This is Release version of code and benchmarking was done on Release as well. BTW, here is benchmark https://gist.github.com/DmitryNaumov/5468cd14b44e55e97366a9bd395bf7a3

Comment: @JonSkeet you're right, I forgot to ask the question!

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah yes, I just found [your blog post about `const decimal`](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/08/22/when-is-a-constant-not-a-constant-when-its-a-decimal/) which explains this behaviour.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: That's exactly what the second half of the post already describes.

Comment: @JonSkeet I clearly haven't woken up yet this morning. :)

Answer (score 6):

If `decimal.MinValue` were only declared as a `static readonly` field, you wouldn't be able to use it as a compile-time constant elsewhere - e.g. for things like the default value of optional parameters.

I suppose the BCL team *could* provide both a constant and a read-only field, but that would confuse many people. If you're in the very rare situation where it makes a difference, introducing your own field looks like an entirely reasonable workaround.

Alternatively, the compiler *could* decide to just copy the value of the field in cases where it's feasible to do so instead of using the constructor. That would potentially end up accessing memory that wouldn't otherwise be touched - micro-tweaks like this can end up with unintended side-effects. I *suspect* that making the compiler handling of this simple was deemed more important than trying to guess what's going to be most efficient in every scenario.

Comment: I wonder what if developer would provide instructions to compiler how to copy struct to another location by, for example, defining an 'copy'-operator: `public static implicit operator decimal(decimal value)`

Comment: @DmitryNaumov: That sounds like it's a rather overcomplicated "fix" for a very narrow problem.